# I write the full python venv path to be able to run manage.py

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, git-bash, manage.py

I have a problem in the virtual environment with django manage.py
I use git bash terminal. and when I activate my venve like this :

> source explorer/Scripts/activate

I successfully activate the environment (explorer text above command line appears) , but still the terminal is pointing to the C:/python37/python.exe path

When i run :

> python manage.py runserver

I receive this error :

**$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 11, in main
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'**

but when I type the absolute path to python.exe inside my virtual environment as follows :

> /explorer/Scripts/python.exe manage.py runserver

, it works fine

I should be just activating the environment and then typing the python manage.py runserver and it should be working

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you install django in your venv? And, if you are using python 3 you should write python3 manage.py runserver. I wait for an answer so I can help you further since the question is relatively unlcear.

Comment: yes , Django is installed in my env. I believe the problem is that the git bash terminal is not pointing to the python inside the virtual env, rather than it is pointing towards the root python

Comment: I think you could find this answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29911962/python-virtualenv-does-not-use-correct-version-of-python